Martingale Coin Tossing Game

Consider a simple coin game where you can bet any amount of money. If it lands on Heads you double your bet; if it lands on Tails you lose your bet. Consider a strategy where you start by betting \$1. If you lose, you will bet \$2. If you lose again, you will bet \$4. If you lose again, you will bet \$8, and so on in this way until you finally win a toss. Once you have won a toss, your strategy has been implemented, and you stop. If you have a total bankroll of \$127 available to implement this strategy, what is your expected profit?

My answer: $\frac{63}{64} = 0.984375$
My thought process:
When we bet \$1, we have a $\frac{1}{2} $ chance of doubling it and receiving a profit of \$1 (\$2 (winning amount) - \$1 (invested amount)). Similarly, when we lose the bet and bet \$2 next time, we have a $\frac{1}{4} $ chance of receiving a profit of \$1 again, and so on till we bet \$64 dollars (because our bankroll is \$127, and if we keep up this strategy, we would bet a series of 1,2,4,8,...,64). Therefore, the expected profit is given by,
$\frac{1}{2} \times (1) + \frac{1}{2^2} \times (1) + \frac{1}{2^3} \times (1) + ... + \frac{1}{2^6} \times (1) = 1 - \frac{1}{64} = 0.984375$
Does this seem right?

what is the expected profit of each individual coin toss?

Not quite. If you want to use your strategy, you need to take into account the probability that you loose every single time, which means you have to add a term $\frac{1}{2^6} \times (-127)$. That being said, you should look at @VáclavMordvinov 's comment for a much more elegant approach.

You neglect the case in which you lose every round.  But, as remarked by @VáclavMordvinov, you don't need to do any calculations at all to get the expected return on this game.

Also, note that you make $7$ (not $6$) bets in total ($2^k$ for $k=0,1,2,3,4,5,6$), hence expected gain is $\sum_{k=0}^62^{-k}=127/128$. Next, with probability $2^{-7}$ you lose everything.

@ShsTht I apologize, that should have been a $1/2^7$ in my comment. I have posted an answer below.

Just copying from/clarifying the comments above.
There are a couple of issues in your calculation. First, you can flip the coin a total of $7$ times, so you are missing an extra $\frac{1}{2^7}\times(1)$ at the end of your sum.
You also need to account for the case in which you flip tails $7$ times in a row. This has probability $\frac{1}{2^7}$, and in that case you lose all $127$ dollars. So we calculate the expected value to be
$$\frac{1}{2}\times(1) + \dots + \frac{1}{2^7}\times(1) - \frac{1}{2^7} \times (127) = 0.$$
The fact that the expected value is "magically" $0$ suggests an alternate explanation. In particular, instead of calculating the expected value by analyzing all end results, we can consider the expected value of each coin flip.
Note that each time you flip a coin while betting $n$ dollars, the expected value is $\frac{1}{2} \times n - \frac{1}{2} \times n = 0$. So each individual coin flip has expected value $0$. Since our betting strategy consists only of (finitely many) coin flips, and each individual coin flip has an expected value of $0$, the entire strategy must have an expected profit of $0$.
